# Function to toggle visibility of tableLayout in android not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button in my XML, that when clicked will toggle the visibility of my TableLayout. This is the XML,

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutAddOns"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Accordion button -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/DisplayAddOns"
                android:layout_width="335dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rarrow"
                android:onClick="ShowAddons"
                android:text="AddOns (Optional)" />
            <!-- Table for add ons -->
              <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableAddOns"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             >

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckGalleryPlus"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Gallery Plus"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckSubtitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Subtitle"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckDesigner"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Designer"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckSupersize"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Supersize"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckScheduled"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Scheduled"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckInternationalVisibility"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="International Visibility"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />                                  

                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckBold"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Bold"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckHighlight"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Highlight"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />                          

                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckFeaturedList"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Featured List"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/CheckFeaturedPlus"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Featured Plus"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />                          

                        </TableRow>

            </TableLayout> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the data from LogCat,

```
04-03 01:21:52.891: D/AndroidRuntime(408): Shutting down VM
04-03 01:21:52.891: W/dalvikvm(408): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught         exception (group=0x40014760)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ShowAddons(View) in the activity class toggler.state.TogglerActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'DisplayAddOns'
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2670)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ShowAddons [class android.view.View]
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.ClassMembers.getConstructorOrMethod(ClassMembers.java:235)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:904)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2663)
04-03 01:21:52.911: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  ... 11 more
```

and this is the Java code,

```
    public void ShowAddons(){

    int TableId = R.id.tableAddOns;

    TableLayout TableVisibility = (TableLayout)findViewById(TableId);


    if(TableVisibility.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        TableVisibility.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    else
    {
        TableVisibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
    }


}
```

It has no errors in eclipse, but when I run it, it says am error has occured and force closes the application. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from LogCat or otherwise tell us what the error is that you're getting?  Can you show us the xml for the table you want to hide?

Comment: Posted the XML file. The LogCat is empty, though

Comment: When you say the system tells you "an error has occurred" and force closes, that is an indication that some kind of uncaught exception has occurred.  There may be no logcat output for your application, but there should be logcat output for the error if you turn all of the filtering off.

Comment: Does the error occur when you press the button, or prior?

Comment: Sorry, I had accidentally cleared the log, I have posted it above. The program closes only when I press the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making `ShowAddOns()` take a `View` argument, as `ShowAddOns(View target)`, even if you don't use the target view in the method.

Comment: @JonO How to do that if you not to want to bind it on the `onClick(View v)`? I get this error if I place it somewhere else without arguments: `The method ShowAddOns(View) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments ()`

Comment: I think you're asking how to invoke the listener method from somewhere other than the bound onClick attribute.  If you're not using the `View` argument inside the method, just pass `null`.